# Force handlebars template to render on demand with meteor

Tags: rendering, meteor, handlebars.js

How can i force a meteor template (handlebars template) to re-render through javascript. For example,

I have a template (template1.html)

```
<template name="template1">
</template>
```

I want to force render this template from anywhere in my `/client` directory. Is there anything in the handlebars package that can do this ?

EDIT: Adding more details

I am not having any difficulties creating this template the first time, either through handlebars or javascript. I want to refresh the template and cause my `rendered` callback to run again. I have code that will fetch and show related data when that template is rendered.

```
<template name="template1">
     {{each items}}
      {{> template2}}
     {{/each}}
 <template/>
```

if any data in items changes then i understand, `template1` and `template2` will both render but what happens when there is any data that changes in `template2`, i would like to refresh/render `template1` again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is changing in template2 that you would see in template 1?  The below would refresh template1 upon an insert or delete.

```
<template name="template1">
  {{itemsCount}} items
  {{#each items}}
  {{> template2}}
  {{/each}}
<template/>
```

Or,

```
    <template name="template1">
      Last updated: {{lastUpdate}}
      {{#each items}}
      {{> template2}}
      {{/each}}
    <template/>

    Template.template1.lastUpdate = function () {
      return Session.get('lastUpdate');
    };
```

Then somewhere you update your data add:

```
    Session.set('lastUpdate', new Date() );
```

Comment: It had to do with non-mongo related data but instead data that comes from an API using an AJAX method to fetch. I was trying to fetch that data and re-render on demand

Comment: You can poll the data, then use the second feature - set something in session (could be just a meaningless flag) and the template referring to it would retrigger.  Rather than lastUpdate, call it APIchanged.

Don't think of it as re-rendering.  Think of it as changing data and watching some template redisplay itself

The alternates to session reactivity would be to learn about deps, http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_autorun, or to add the data you retrieve to a local collection.

Comment: I actually did end up using Deps.autorun to run a reactive computation with a session variable similar to what you have in your last comment and that has been working for me. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

### FOR NEW VERSIONS OF METEOR USE [UI.render() and UI.insert()](http://docs.meteor.com/#ui)

---

---

---

### defunc - for versions of meteor that don't use blaze

Can you provide some more context?

Inside a html file to render that template simply use:

```
<div id="somediv">
    {{> template1}}
</div>
```

If you want to do this through javascript one way would be:

```
$('#somediv').html(Meteor.render(Template.template1));
```

Take a look at:

- http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_render
- http://handlebarsjs.com/
- https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/examples/todos/client/todos.html

Comment: Yess, thank you for the Javascript function. That solved a problem for me :)